# Find the area of the surface given by the parametrization.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Find the area of the surface given by the parametrization: 
> $\vec r(u,v)=((2+\cos(u))\cos(v),(2+\cos(u))\sin(v), \sin(u))$ while $0 \le u,v \le 2\pi$.

I have tried to solve this question using the given parametrization in the normal way by finding $\vec r_u \times \vec r_v$. 
But things got really complicated with all the $\cos, \sin$ with two different parameters. 
I was wondering if there's any cool tricks or other ways I couldn't see in order to solve this question. 
Thanks in advance. 
Note: Final answer is $8\pi^2$

Comment: It's a torus. Search in this site for "torus surface", it is plenty of useful results. At least five ways of make it easier.

Comment: @RafaBudría Thank you, I haven't tbh heard of that, I will try to read about it. but is there any way to make it easier without knowing it's a torus? since I received this question without ever hearing about a torus, or it was intended to be solved normally?

Comment: Following the, say, general method is not that messy. Things simplify a lot very quickly. Do the cross product group terms and use the trigonometric identity. Then calculate its norm, group and simplify. The final expression is really simple.

Comment: this parametrization is not bad to go about the surface integral. However you can check this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1315349/surface-area-of-a-torus

Comment: Here is one that uses the same parametrization. You can see the steps and simplifications. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83269/surface-area-of-torus-of-revolution